# Python reload() to get var in While loop

Tags: python, while-loop, unicorn

Just started with Python, so the following code is probably very poor, but it works for now.

**I have the following issue;**
I'm using the Pimoroni Unicorn Hat (led hat) for Raspberry Pi, the only way to keep the leds lighted is with a loop. To turn the leds/animations off and on i've created multiple Python files:

- Control-Led.py (defined the animations for variable a)
- var.py (writes the argument i use to a .txt file which is variable a)
- getvar.py (reads the var from the txt file)
- var.txt (file which contains the variable)

The issue i have is that i continuous need to `reload(getvar)` in order to update the variable from the txt file in the control-led.py, in the first `While True` i have a `time.sleep(2)` so that's no issue, but in the second loop i needed to set a `time.sleep(0.01)` in order to get the animation of the led working. So every 0.01 second the value gets updated now.. it's causing high CPU and i think this is not the correct method.

Can you guys help me out please?

**Control-led.py**

```
    import varget
import time
import math
import unicornhat as unicorn

unicorn.set_layout(unicorn.HAT)
unicorn.rotation(90)
unicorn.brightness(0.5)
width,height=unicorn.get_shape()

'''
VARS

0. Turn off
1. Turn on white light
2. Home Axis animation
'''


while True:
        reload(varget)
        time.sleep(2)

        if varget.a == 0:
                unicorn.off()
        elif varget.a == 1:
                unicorn.set_all(255,255,255)
                unicorn.show()
        elif varget.a == 2:
                i = 0.0
                offset = 30
                while varget.a == 2:
                        i = i + 0.3
                        for y in range(height):
                                for x in range(width):
                                        r = 0
                                        g = 0
                                        r = (math.cos((x+i)/2.0) + math.cos((y+i)/2.0)) * 64.0 + 128.0
                                        g = (math.sin((x+i)/1.5) + math.sin((y+i)/2.0)) * 64.0 + 128.0
                                        b = (math.sin((x+i)/2.0) + math.cos((y+i)/1.5)) * 64.0 + 128.0
                                        r = max(0, min(255, r + offset))
                                        g = max(0, min(255, g + offset))
                                        b = max(0, min(255, b + offset))
                                        unicorn.set_pixel(x,y,int(r),int(g),int(b))
                        unicorn.show()
                        time.sleep(0.01)
                        reload(varget)
```

**var.py**

```
import sys

print sys.argv[1]
file = open("./var.txt", "w")
file.write(sys.argv[1])
file.close
```

**varget.py**

```
f = open('var.txt')
contents = f.read()
file_as_list = contents.splitlines()
for line in file_as_list:
  print(line)
a = int(line)
```

Comment: As you mentioned, you're reading the variable from the file. I think that is the real reason causing the extra delay

Comment: Yes, but it's getting really high when the getvar.a == 2.. because it's looping every 0.01 sec. I need to get rid of that reload function in that loop. Or make it some way that it's reloading every 2 sec in that loop...